# How do I make child take up rest of the space while still being scrollable

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Using Tailwind, I have a header and a child `div` that is scrollable but the scrollable div takes up more space than it should. I want to make sure that the scrollable `div` doesn't exceed the height of its container. Right now, the page scrolls and the header isn't the height it should be

```
<div class="flex h-screen flex-col">
  <div class="h-48 bg-white">some content</div>
  <div class="h-full pb-9">
    <div class="h-full overflow-y-scroll bg-red-300 [&>*]:px-4" id="content">
      <div class="sticky top-0 z-50 flex items-start justify-between bg-red-300 py-4">
        <div>
          <h2 class="text-xl">header</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="h-full">
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
        <h1 class="text-7xl">too much height</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/7ksq08Tm2P

I tried setting `overflow-hidden` on the top level parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `min-h-0` class to `<div class="h-full pb-9">`, because the flex child normally has `min-height: auto`, like this:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/BFQ0Xah5gA